# How to grease an internal hub gear?

Tags: internally-geared-hub

Are there any online tutorials or can someone explain how to grease an internal hub gear?

I did a bit of searching but I only find people completely desassembling their hub gears. I am looking for a more practical day-to-day example.

Comment: What IGH is it? You can look in the [manual](http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-CASG001-00-ENG.pdf) for your hub to find this (linked is an example for a Nexus Inter-8 which uses oil), as the procedure is not the same between hubs. Sheldon Brown has some other [examples](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/nexus-mech.html#lubrication) which use a grease.

Comment: Is there a problem with it? If not (and you're not up for disassembling it) don't mess with it. If there is, get LBS to service it; they will flush it, clear out the rust/etc., and grease it so it'll be good for years. See also [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20593/internal-gear-hub-maintenance).

Comment: You really should follow the manufacturer's recommendation for servicing and especially service intervals.  Generally that's a drain and refil every 12 months or x000 km.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you will find a nipple on the hub that allows you to drain out the gear oil and then replace with new fresh oil which greases the gears. The placement and instructions for doing this depend largely on the type and brand.

Comment: Note that this is only the case for the 11 gear model; other models need an "oil bath" instead, where you dunk it in Shimano oil. See https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/sm/SM-IHG-INTER8_ENG.pdf